# angularjs - custom property become empty

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to `unshift` a object to existing array list. But when i do that, i am getting one of the value is `empty`. what is the correct way to push a new object to existing array in `angularjs`?

here is my code :

```
 var staticPhase = {

                  "DisciplineId": "0",
                  "DisciplineName": "All",
                  "PhaseId": "0",
                  "PhaseName": "All" // but this is being converted as ''
                }

            if($scope.firstLoad) {

                var newList = angular.copy( $scope.project.ProjectSummaryFilter ); //taking a copy of existing array

                var filterById = $filter('filter')(newList, { ProjectId : $scope.projectId })[0];

                staticPhase.ProjectId = filterById.ProjectId;           
                staticPhase.ProjectName = filterById.ProjectName;           
                staticPhase.SubProjectId = filterById.SubProjectId;           
                staticPhase.SubProjectName = filterById.SubProjectName;  

            }


            var phaseList = $scope.project.ProjectSummaryFilter;
                            phaseList.unshift(staticPhase) //adding static phase to array;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard JavaScript `push()` method should work:

```
var phaseList = $scope.project.ProjectSummaryFilter;
phaseList.push(staticPhase);
```

Comment: `unshift` wont work? i would like to add the array as first one in the list

Comment: still i am using `push` - not working. getting result as empty ('')

Comment: Yes, unshift() should work. Can you post the rest of your code? (the part where you are accessing the array and getting empty)